# Error in Ionic App's javascript: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, paypal, ionic-framework

guys!

I'm having some trouble with javascript in Ionic. I'm trying to make a request to another site, and I'm having this error message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

My Ionic App have already the plugin whitelist installed and up to date, my config.xml file allow navigation and access of every location. I've tried also to execute chrome with security disabled and it didn't work either.

Could anyone help? Don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, XMLHttpRequests are limited to same domain requests (i.e. request between localhost and localhost or request between paypal.com and paypal.com).

Cross-site XMLHttpRequests (like from localhost to paypal.com) are disabled by default as a security feature in modern browsers, in order to bypass this security feature, the destination server should explicitly allow cross-site requests and this is done by sending back a header called "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" with either * or specific domain as value, for example when a server replies back with the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

It is telling the browser of visitor that I'm accepting an XMLHttpRequest from **any domain**.

In your case, you are doing a request on https://**svcs.sandbox.paypal.com**/AdaptivePayments/Pay which doesn't allow cross-site requests (no Access-Control-Allow-Origin is present) and thus the browser is blocking XMLHttpRequest from going through.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test your `http://localhost:8100` (LOCALHOST) to paypal services/api's that requires communication with your script, except if you use tunnel hosts, like https://ngrok.com/, https://localtunnel.me/. Your scripts that run in your localhost should be accessible to the world wide web, so that it is visible to Paypal.